# Docker container not starts if syslog server is not available for logging

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, containers, syslog

I am having a strange but known issue, which is I configured syslog as my logging driver but due to some reasons its not always mandatory for my server to be available due to network connectivity issues. But i want my container to be started without any problem and keeps trying to dial TCP connection of syslog for sync if possible, but container not starts at all complaining about syslog that its not accessible.

I have different services in my docker compose but to understand the issue I just included single service with Google's DNS IP making sure it will fail always.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    container_name: backend
    mem_limit: 1200m
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp:/8.8.8.8:514"
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 60 --workers=1 --threads=3 --worker-connections=50
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mlbridge
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

What I did already tried is

```
mode: "non-blocking"
```

but this is not helping me